# Excel formula help please?

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice

I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out as I am frying my brain with this.

I am trying to figure out how to input the formula so if and when numbers are entered, the total is shown.

Like for example:

I input how many, and what size and it gives me the total... But I'm trying to get it so the formula only shows amount when numbers are entered. But the formula I have entered in the cost column still shows an amount when even the how many and size cells are empty...

=A14*B14+3

But when A14 and B14 are blank, C14 is showing $3 in the column. I know its from the +3, but I need that there in order to get the correct amount when data is entered.

I hope I am making sense.

Incase anyone needs to know, I am using the free software Open Office.

Any help would be seriously appreciated. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 1):

You can chain an AND logical operator using the IF function within the ISBLANK function, to calculate the formula only if A14 AND B14 are not empty. In pseudocode: IF NOT ISBLANK(A14) AND NOT ISBLANK(B14) THEN C14 = A14*B14+3

Here some resources: https://exceljet.net/formula/if-cell-is-not-blank

Comment: -1, although the answer is correct, the text in the codeblock is not an excel formula, meaning that OP has to do research in order to get it to work. The code in the block should be the correct excel formula, `=IF(NOT(ISBL....)`

Comment: Linkout does say it is "pseudocode" in the text, he also then provides a link with adequate resources for the author of the question to put the formula together themselves and learn how it all functions in the process. Maybe just remove the code tags rather than give a -1, as this site is supposed to encourage people to research and learn rather than be a source to solve your problems for you?

Comment: It actually it looks like the code tags have been added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=IF(OR(A14="",B14=""),"",A14*B14+3)
```

This says return *blank* until **both** inputs have been entered.